# Plot pandas dataframe with varying number of columns along imshow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot an image and a pandas bar plot side by side in an iPython notebook. This is part of a function so that the dataframe containing the values for the bar chart can vary with respect to number of columns.

The libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline
```

Dataframe

```
faces = pd.Dataframe(...) # return values for 8 characteristics
```

This returns the the bar chart I'm looking for and works for a varying number of columns.

```
faces.plot(kind='bar').set_xticklabels(result[0]['scores'].keys())
```

But I didn't find a way to plot it in a pyplot figure also containing the image. This is what I tried:

```
fig, (ax_l, ax_r) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 5))
ax_l.imshow( img )
ax_r=faces.plot(kind='bar').set_xticklabels(result[0]['scores'].keys())
```

The output i get is the image on the left and an empty plot area with the correct plot below. There is

```
ax_r.bar(...)
```

but I couldn't find a way around having to define the columns to be plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify your axes object in your `DataFrame.plot` calls.

In other words: `faces.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax_r)`